# delete a cached image with liip

Tags: file, symfony, liipimaginebundle

I want to delete the deleted image from the cache. I made a listener but I can't remove the photo from the cache:

```
$this->cm->remove($entity->getFilename(), 'thumb');
```

I don't use vichbundle. I don't understand why I can't.

Thanks a lot

Comment: The first parameter must be the path of the image

Comment: the image path and not the cache path?

Comment: The path of the original image that you want to delete not the cache and liip will delete the cache

Comment: ok but I can't access parameters:
    images_directory: '%kernel.project_dir%/public/uploads' to tell it which image to delete!

Comment: Attempted to call an undefined method named "getParameter" of class =>  $this->cm->remove($this->getParameter('images_directory').$entity->getFilename(), 'thumb');

Comment: I have posted an answer with two examples to get the path of image

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To access to image path you can make a function inside your entity:

```
class Image {

    public function getWebPath(): string
    {
       // name should have the extension (1556989965.jpeg)
        return __DIR__ . '/../../public/uploads/images' . '/' . $this->getName();
    }

    // Or try like this:

    // directory inside public folder
    const UPLOAD_DIR = 'uploads/images';

    //folder
    public function getUploadDir(): string
    {
       return $this::UPLOAD_DIR;
    }

    public function getWebPath(): string
    {
        return $this->getUploadDir() . '/' . $this->getName();
    }

   

}
```

and to remove cache:

```
$this->cm->remove($entity->getWebPath(), 'thumb');
```

Comment: Sincerely, I've been on this function for 5 days... thank you very much for unblocking me! thank you